# Best way to parse a complex log file?

Tags: regex, parsing, csv

I need to parse a log file that consist in many screenshot of real-time OS stdout.
In particular, every section of my log_file.txt is a text version of what appear on screen. In this machine there's not monitor, so the stdout is written on a downloadable log_file.txt.
The aim would be to create a .csv of this file for data mining purpose but I'm still wondering what could be the best method to compute this file.
I would the first csv file line with the description (string) of the value and from the second line I would the respective values (int).

I was thinking about a parser generator (JavaCC, ANTLR, etc..) but before starting with them I would get some opinions.
Thank you.

P.S.
I put a short version of my log at the following link: pastebin.com/r9t3PEgb

Comment: Your question is definitely *not* answerable until you provide an example of your log file and the data you want to extract.

Comment: Have you tried Splunk (http://www.splunk.com/en_us/download.html) ?

Comment: I put a short version of my log at the following link: http://pastebin.com/r9t3PEgb

Comment: I do not think that Splunk is what I need. I need something that transform the log "unstructured" file in a "structured" csv file.